# Копирование записей из одной таблицы

Tags: sql

Как сделать копирование записей из одной таблицы в другую, и потом обновить одно поле с данными из другой таблицы средствами sql запросов?
Есть три таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE [vedomost] (
  [id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  [fio] VARCHAR(80), 
  [dolgnost] VARCHAR(80), 
  [stavky] FLOAT, 
  [work_days] INTEGER, 
  [shtraf] FLOAT, 
  [nalog] FLOAT, 
  [prochee] FLOAT, 
  [avans] FLOAT, 
  [premija] FLOAT, 
  [month] VARCHAR(30), 
  [year] INTEGER, 
  [point] VARCHAR(80), 
  [n_month] INTEGER, 
  [status] BOOLEAN);

CREATE TABLE [dolgnosty] (
  [id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,      
  [dolgnost] VARCHAR(80));

CREATE TABLE [stavky] (
  [id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  
  [dolgnost] VARCHAR(80), 
  [stavka] FLOAT,
  [year] VARCHAR(30),
  [month] VARCHAR(30), 
  [point] VARCHAR(80), 
  [n_month] INTEGER);
```

Вопрос в следующем. Надо скопировать из таблицы dolgnosty все значения поля [dolgnost] в таблицу stavky, а потом в таблице stavky вставить значения в поле [stavka] из таблицы vedomost, из поля [stavky].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO stavky (id, dolgnost) SELECT DISTINCT id, dolgnost FROM dolgnosty
```

второй запрос аналогично
небольшие замечания 1) в stavky название должности наверно лишнее 2) мало ли - вдруг ваши программы будут смотреть иностранцы. идентификаторы лучше давать на английском

Answer (score 1):

Задача поставлена некорректно, ввиду некорректности структуры.
Никуда ничего вставлять не нужно, если правильно определить внешние ключи. Например,
[stavky].[dolgnost] должно быть внешним ключом к таблице dolgnosty и иметь, соответственно, тип int. И т.д.